# Dividing posts in dynamic categories based on likes and comments in django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I have two tables in django which are Post and Comment such as

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    desc = models.TextField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

 class Comment(models.Model):
     comment = models.CharField()
     user    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     post    = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now on home page I want to show posts divided based on no of likes and comments.

For example:

1. Category 1 will have posts which have likes and comments between 0-5
2. Category 2 will have posts which have likes and comments between 6-10
3. Category 3 will have posts which have likes and comments between 10-15
4. Category 4 will have posts which have likes and comments between 15 and above.

I wrote following query for Category 1

```
 posts= Post.objects.annotate(total_likes=Count('likes')).filter(total_likes__lte=5) \
.annotate(total_comments=Count('comment__comment')).filter(total_comments__lte=5)
```

But problem is that it is only returning data when when both are under limit, if likes are 6 but comment are less than 5 then i want it to be in Category 1, Unless both conditions satisfy, Same for other categories, I did not found any helpful solutions so far.

How can we implement this dynamic categorization in Django ORM?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` operator with `Q`:

```
from django.db.models import Q

posts= Post.objects.annotate(
    total_likes=Count('likes'), 
    total_comments=Count('comment__comment'),
).filter(
    Q(total_likes__lte=5) | # this is OR
    Q(total_comments__lte=5),
)
```